# jquery button mouseenter hide/show text

Tags: jquery, button, text

My question is about jquery

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/dengort/xpvt214o/922392/>
```

why is going the second button down when im entering the first button???

Thanks for helping. :D

Comment: Your question is not clear. Explain

Comment: when im entering the first button i dont want that the second button is going down a bit. sorry i cant explain it better im from Germany :/

Comment: When you hover over button 1, it is going down a bit. There is no mouseenter action for the second button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the button from going down on mouse hover, add 'float: left' to nav button.

```
nav button{
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;

    min-width: 160px;
    min-height: 160px;
    max-width: 180px;
    max-height: 180px;

    display: inline-block;

    margin: 7.5px 40px;

    position: static;

    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    float:left;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeeahh thank you finally i got an solution. Last question how am i getting the buttons to the center of the screen?

Comment: both buttons in the center, second one below first. Like this?

Comment: Please appreciate the contributor's effort by upvoting if you find the answer helpful.

Comment: could you show me what you mean in a css file ?